# Variable is getting incremented incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

I am writing following JS code with protractor. Here I used a data.json file to read data for my test case. Within this test case, I am simple reading the item from this JSON and comparing it with a value that I am reading from the browser.

Problem that I am facing here is in my Expect statement,the value from JSON file is not correct.

Could any one please help to identify the problem here.

```
    var datafile = require('./Data.json')

    beforeEach(() => {
       browser.get("https://angularjs.org");  
     });  

    describe('Test Angular Page ', () => 
     {

       it('user name should be displayed correctly #try', () =>    
        { 

          var count = datafile.length; 

          for (var i=0; i<count; i++)  
              {
                var value = datafile[i];               
                browser.refresh();
                element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys(value); 
                (element(by.binding('yourName'))).getText()
                        .then(function (txt)
                               {                                                                        
                           expect(txt).toEqual('Hello '+ value+'!'); 
                          //this is failing                             
})

       }       
      });
```

below is my data.json

```
  [
   "A1","A2","A3"
  ]
```

below is some part of the result-

```
 1) Test Angular Page  user name should be displayed correctly #try
  Message:
   Expected 'Hello A1!' to equal 'Hello A3!'.
   Stack:
      Error: Failed expectation
       at D:\Demo_Protractor\test.spec.js:24:44
        at elementArrayFinder_.then (C:\User  s\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.ts:840:22)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_   (C:\Users\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2813:27)
    at C:\Users\leenasharma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
     Message:
        Expected 'Hello A2!' to equal 'Hello A3!'.
      Stack:
      Error: Failed expectation
```

Comment: Take a look at [Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/4472840)

Answer (score 1):

```
it('user name should be displayed correctly #try', () => {
  var count = datafile.length;
  var value, i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    value = datafile[i];
    browser.refresh();
    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys(value);
    (element(by.binding('yourName'))).getText()
      .then(function(txt) {
        expect(txt).toEqual('Hello ' + value + '!');
        //this is failing                             
      })
  }
});
```

`var` has only function level scope, there is no block level scope. Adding `var value` inside for loop doesn't create variables for each iteration. It will be hoisted to top of fuction with variable hoisting. Your `getText()` is asynchronous, by the time the `then` is called loop finishes and `value` become the value assignedd in last iteration ie. `A3`.

As a solution, you can use es6 `let` instead of `var` to declare your `value`. `let` will give you block level scope.

```
it('user name should be displayed correctly #try', () => {
  var count = datafile.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let value = datafile[i];
    browser.refresh();
    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys(value);
    (element(by.binding('yourName'))).getText()
      .then(function(txt) {
        expect(txt).toEqual('Hello ' + value + '!');
        //this is failing                             
      })
  }
});
```

That being said, the latest versions of protractor/jasmine doesnt require `getText()` handled this way with `then`. Which version of angular, jasmine and protractor are you using?

> `expect()` determines whether the parameter is a promise or not and
>   executes asynchronously or synchronously based on that.

Why are you doing `browser.refresh()` on each iteration? The intention is not clear to me.

Comment: regarding browser.refresh, I tried to do run this test case everytime on a fresh page. I could have used clear function also. experimenting and learning. The solution that Steve gave in his response below is also working. and now I am trying to relate both. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are checking the value in a promise which is done async.

Refactor your code so expect() resolves the promise for you:

```
expect(element(by.binding('yourName'))).getText())).toEqual('Hello '+ value+'!');
```

More information can be found [on the protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow)

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve!

Comment: as mentioned above, I am trying to understand how the scoping issue of a variable got resolved by using expect. Are there any good pointers\references to understand these async concepts of JS?